# Vuetify slider append slot text field is not aligned with slider

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify slider with one minus icon in the prepend slot, and one plus icon in the append slot.
If I add one more text field to the append slot, the plus icon and text field are not aligned with the slider. How can I make them aligned?

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/yejianfengblue/pen/QWGdRRO)

```html
<v-app id="app">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>Vuetify Slider append slot is not aligned if more than one element</v-card-title>
    <v-subheader>Append slot contains only one plus icon, the plus icon is aligned with the slider</v-subheader>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-slider v-model="bpm" track-color="grey" always-dirty thumb-label="always" min="1" max="422">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <v-icon :color="color" @click="bpm--">
            mdi-minus
          </v-icon>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:append>
          <v-icon :color="color" @click="bpm++">
            mdi-plus
          </v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-slider>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-subheader>Append slot contains one icon and one text field, the plus icon and text field are not aligned with the slider</v-subheader>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-slider v-model="bpm" track-color="grey" always-dirty thumb-label="always" min="1" max="422">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <v-icon :color="color" @click="bpm--">
            mdi-minus
          </v-icon>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:append>
          <v-icon :color="color" @click="bpm++">
            mdi-plus
          </v-icon>
          <!-- The only difference is this text field-->
          <v-text-field v-model="bpm"></v-text-field>
        </template>
      </v-slider>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-app>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    bpm: 10
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected to have only one element on each slot. But you can set css for that element and wrap it with `v-layout`.

```html
<template v-slot:append>
   <v-layout class="alignThis">
      <v-icon :color="color" @click="bpm++">
         mdi-plus
      </v-icon>
      <v-text-field
         v-model="bpm"
         class="mb-1 pt-0"
         type="number"
         style="width: 60px"
         ></v-text-field>
   </v-layout>
</template>
```

With style:

```css
<style>
.alignThis {
   margin-top: -18px !important;
}
</style>
```

And `v-text-field` has his own css properties, you can override it also with `!important` or with SaSS variables.

[Live example](https://codepen.io/proofzy/pen/XWNMMMd)